# How to reorder the test case number on Testlink?

Tags: testlink

I have around 200 test cases for my system stored and managed using Testlink. However, I noticed that when I deleted one test case, the latest number of test cases still remains 200.

Is there any way to automatically adjust the test case count id every time the user deletes a test case or simply re-orders the test case sequence.

Thanks